# Sonar qube is not getting started

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

while running the StartSonar.bat from command line I am getting the following error contineously.sonarqube log file is showing the below messages.

Any help is always appreciated!

```
    --> Wrapper Started as Console
     Launching a JVM...
  Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
 Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

     2015.06.13 15:04:41 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch     process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java -    Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true   -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.1\sonarqube-5.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\rkutchar\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process3411693551115002418properties
     2015.06.13 15:04:42 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
    2015.06.13 15:04:42 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
    2015.06.13 15:04:42 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434188081817] version[1.4.4], pid[7068], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
    2015.06.13 15:04:42 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434188081817] initializing ...
  2015.06.13 15:04:42 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1434188081817] loaded [], sites []
  2015.06.13 15:04:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434188081817] initialized
  2015.06.13 15:04:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434188081817] starting ...
   2015.06.13 15:04:44 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1434188081817] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/10.76.17.174:9001]}
   2015.06.13 15:04:44 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1434188081817] sonarqube/Y7PopLbZQ8Gqvlg6o70C3g
  2015.06.13 15:04:47 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1434188081817] new_master [sonar-1434188081817][Y7PopLbZQ8Gqvlg6o70C3g][DIN35003079][inet[/10.76.17.174:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1434188081817}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
  2015.06.13 15:04:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1434188081817] started
  2015.06.13 15:04:47 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1434188081817] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
  2015.06.13 15:04:48 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
  2015.06.13 15:04:48 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\sonarqube-5.1\sonarqube-5.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\sonarqube-5.1\sonarqube-5.1\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\rkutchar\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process4890757865030388998properties
  2015.06.13 15:04:49 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
   2015.06.13 15:04:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: D:\sonarqube-5.1\sonarqube-5.1\web
  2015.06.13 15:04:49 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
  2015.06.13 15:04:49 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
  2015.06.13 15:04:50 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1434188081817] loaded [], sites []
  2015.06.13 15:04:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1 / 4aa9af3a6a4362b61db365fba32eb0a55d411e7a
  2015.06.13 15:04:50 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
  2015.06.13 15:04:50 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:117) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:73) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
 at     org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766) ~[picocontainer-2.14.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:96) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
   Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.checkConnection(DefaultDatabase.java:115) ~[sonar-core-5.1.jar:na]
... 27 common frames omitted
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:5.1.34]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
... 30 common frames omitted
 2015.06.13 15:04:51 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370)   2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b15 [Windows 7-amd64]
2015.06.13 15:04:51 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
```

EDIT:

```
     apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

     sonarRunner {
     sonarProperties {
       // can be also set on command line like -         Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental

    property "sonar.host.url","http://localhost:9000"
    property "sonar.jdbc.url","jdbc:mysql://sonar.someserver.int:3306/sonar"
    property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    property "sonar.jdbc.username", "****"
    property "sonar.jdbc.password", "****"

    //I added these properties to my gradle.build
    property "sonar.projectKey","com.example.rkutchar.myapplication"
    property "sonar.projectName","MyApplication"
    property "sonar.projectVersion","V1.0"
    property "sonar.language","java"
    property "sonar.sources","src/main/java"
    property "sonar.binaries","build"
   }
   }

    subprojects {
     sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        properties["sonar.sources"] += "src/main/java"
      }
   }
   }
    sonarRunner {
toolVersion = '2.4'
 }
```

PROJECT.PROPERTIES FILE

```
     # Required metadata
     sonar.projectKey=MyApplication
     sonar.projectName=My Application
     sonar.projectVersion=1.0

     # Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
     sonar.sources=src/main/java

     # Language
     sonar.language=java

     # Encoding of the source files
     sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

conf/sonar-properties

```
  #Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube DB details for example
  #No information about specific project should appear here

  #----- Default SonarQube server
  #sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

  #----- PostgreSQL
  #sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

  #----- MySQl
  sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?     
  useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

   #----- Oracle
   #sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

#----- Microsoft SQLServer
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor

 #----- Global database settings
#sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Security (when 'sonar.forceAuthentication' is set to 'true')
#sonar.login=admin
#sonar.password=admin
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the permissions are not correct on your database. You have to execute the following statement on your MySQL database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sonar`.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost';
```

Comment: +1,Thanks a lot for the answer and I have done that but after executing the command I have tried to run my sonar runner but its giving the following errors  ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown':   sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
ERROR:

Comment: See my edited question for my build.properties file and sonar-properties file as well

Comment: You mix analyzer and server. Both require DB connections (until version 5.2). The logs you sent are about server whereas the configuration is about analyzer. So you should check your server configuration (conf/sonar.properties) before fixing analyzer.

Comment: @Simon Brandhof, Thanks for the suggestion.I have just edited my question and copied my conf/sonar.properties file.could you please have a look at that??Am I missing anything in that file??

Comment: Are the whitespaces in the JDBC URL expected ? (just before "useUnicode"). As @Mithfindel explained, you should check the access rights, and of course the existence of DB user and schema named "sonar".

Comment: whitespaces before unicode is a typo and edited it.I have created the db with name sonar and I have got access rights as well. The problem is I want to analyse for an android project and its not working at all.I dont undestand where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained, you should do step by step. First start server then analyze your android project. No need to spend your time on analyzer as long as server is not correctly started.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly you placed the jdbc driver in the right folder. So it cant be realted to JDBC driver absence. Double check this.

I think you might have gotton the sonar.JDBC url property wrong. What DB is it?

Regards,
Karthik Prabhu